# How to update Xcode beta?

Tags: xcode, ide

For Mac / iOS developers, there is a period that we have to use Xcode beta version so as to build a test environment for the new/pre-released version of OS X / iOS. So my question is:

What is the standard process of updating Xcode beta version, for example, from beta 1 to beta 2?

Is it necessary to remove beta 1 completely and then install a newly downloaded beta 2?

Is there any shortcut to achieve this process?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since Beta releases are generally released to developers with Apple Developer Account, a standard process of updating:

- Login to Apple Developer Account
- Go to iOS Dev / Mac Dev / Safari Dev Beta content
- Follow links to download and install Beta releases

Multiple versions of Xcode can be Maintained. E.g I have Xcode Beta 1 installed in `/Applications/Xcode 6/Beta 1/` and Beta 2 installed in `/Applications/Xcode 6/Beta 2/`. As of speaking now, Xcode 6 Beta 3 is released, you can install that on `/Applications/Xcode 6/Beta 3/`. Here is [link](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) to get started.

Also note that to setup app testing environment with Beta releases, there is good [reference here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html).

Beta releases are not on iTunes so we can't take advantage of one click update.

Comment: its 2017, i wish we'd make things less manual and support updates for betas as well, i wonder what happened to the automate-everything manifesto.